# Compare Set of different types in Junit

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to compare two Set of different types in Java.

Lets consider of

```
 Set<Person>
```

and

```
 Set<PersonResponse>
```

where Person and PersonResponse are basically POJOs like.

```
class Person {
   String personName;
   String education;
   int age; 
 }

 class PersonResponse {
   String pName;
   String pEducation;
   int pAge; 
   int responseStatus;
 }
```

Now , I am trying to write a method that actually compare the name , education and age from PersonResponse and Person.

```
public boolean comparePerson(Set<Person> actual, Set<PersonResponse> response)
```

At the same time , Name is not a unique. I was thinking to make use of an index , but cant do so in this case.

The responseStatus from PersonResponse does not matter whatever the value is.

Any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you overridden equals and hashCode in those POJOs?

Comment: No , they dont have equals and Hashcode

Comment: Well the easiest way would be override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Person`. Can you change this class, or is that not possible?

Comment: Well , I am working on a method that helps me to compare without using equals and hashCode.

Comment: A pretty simple way would be to transform each Person and PersonResponse in a String representation that only contains your important values (and is unique for this data, for example by using seperator characters that don't apppear in the data itself). Then you can make two sets/lists/whatever of these string representations (from your Person and PersonResponse sets) and call `set1.equals(set2)`. Another way would to to transform one list into a hashmap and then iterate over the other one, comparing each entry to the hashmap by key/etc.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the wrong data structure.  If PersonResponse contains a Person object (instead of the separate fields) you have no need to compare.  Can you change your Java beans?

Or further you could do away with PersonResponse class and you could ultimately have this:

```
Map<Person, List<Integer>> personResponses = new HashMap<>();
//...
List<Integer> responsesForSomeone = personResponses.get(somePerson);
```